# Angular Universal - How to trigger manually the state change from server side to client view?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

We have a simple Angular Universal app using angular/cli: 1.4.3
(and node: 6.9.5).

We manage to configure the server side view. When the dom is ready, we switch to a client view. But, the switch is made before we collect all the data needed from the API. So there is a moment right after the switch when the page is displayed without the data.

**Is there any way to trigger manually the switch between the 2 states?** In this case, we want to display the client view after we get the response from the API.

Here is the simplified example we made for this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        './styles/glh.css'
    ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    public hotel: any;
    public id: number = null;

    constructor(
        public http: Http,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
            this.id = params.id;
          if(this.id) {
            this.getHotel(this.id).subscribe(hotel => {
              this.hotel = hotel;
            });
          }
        });
    }

    private getHotel(hotelId: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`https://api.example.com/v1/example/${hotelId}`)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .map((data: any) => {
                return data;
            });
    }

    protected extractData(res: Response) {
        return res.json() || { };
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular's route resolver to avoid the blink. See [Angular Routing docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating) for more information.

If you fetch your data in the resolver, Angular will only route to your component (and initialize it) when the data is already there. Since the switch happens after everything is initialized, it is absolutely smooth and without any blink.

Comment: Good idea! We are trying that for the moment, I'll let you know the result.

Comment: We've done the same, so it works for sure :) Though, additionally we do transfer the API data in the SSR file (so the API is called on server side and the results are written into the .html file so that the client can just read it without another API call)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for us! This was the perfect answer :-)