# Angular Universal Reload twice

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Angular Universal App reload the content twice for the initial code, how to prevent this?

I have put my initial code in ngOnInit() still getting the same result.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using...? Try to post package.json and few elements of your component

Comment: Maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471986/angular-universal-how-to-trigger-manually-the-state-change-from-server-side-to?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score -2):

Angular Universal first prerenders the js of your project in server side and then once the dom is rendered it switches to the client side, irrespective of the data fetched. Make sure you don't call the data or APIs again once you get it. This should help to stop the second reload.

Comment: How would you propose to avoid the API calls the second time ? Any way to transfer state from server to browser ?

Comment: Question is, how?

Comment: did you found a solution for this?